# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser is not displaying the page

Tags: wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to programmatically add a ChromiumWebBrowser control to an application I'm developing. These are the steps I'm following:

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings()
{
    PackLoadingDisabled = true,
};

Cef.Initialize(settings);

_webControl = new ChromiumWebBrowser()
{
    Width = this.ElementWidth,
    Height = this.ElementHeight
};

_webControl.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
    _webControl.Address = "http://www.google.com";
};

grid.Children.Add(_webControl);
```

But I can't get it displaying anything. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was doing

```
grid.Children.Add(_webControl);
```

before

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Swapping the order made the code work.